# Run docker on windows 10

Tags: docker

I installed docker in windows 10 machine without changing anything in the default features.

I double click the docker button in order to open the connection with docker and I receive this error

```
Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS. See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#virtualization
```

As a result I can't run the docker. Any help for this?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear from the error message, and the details in the link that's provided - there are features either in your machine's BIOS, or within Windows, that you need to enable before Docker will be able to run.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the basic requirements as mentioned on the official page:

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/

[image]

For enabling virtualization follow the steps mentioned at : https://mashtips.com/enable-virtualization-windows-10/